# mdx group by measures values range

Tags: group-by, range, mdx, measures

I'm looking for the way to create a group by measure value.
I have a cube of bookings with the dimensions, client, supplier.... and more dimensions.
I want to create a query, which  must returns the suppliers grouped by Total amount range and count of suppliers that contains each group.

I have created a query which  returns for each supplier which his range total amount, that one looks like this:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Range1] as fix([Measures].[Total Amount]/1000)*1000, FORMAT_STRING = "###############0"
    MEMBER [Measures].[Range2] as fix([Measures].[Total Amount]/1000 + 1 )*1000 - 1, FORMAT_STRING = "###############0"

    MEMBER [Measures].[MyRange] AS 
        iif([Measures].[Total Amount] >= 0,
            Cast([Measures].[Range1] as string) ||" - "||  Cast([Measures].[Range2] as string), 
            NULL)

   SET supli AS
       Order(filter([Supplier].[Supplier].Members,[Measures].[Total Amount] >= 0),
             [Measures].[Total Amount],BASC)

    MEMBER [Measures].[rank] AS 
        iif([Measures].[Total Amount] >= 0, 
            rank([Supplier].[Supplier].currentMember,supli), 
            NULL), FORMAT_STRING = "#####0"

    MEMBER [Supplier].[Range] as Aggregate([Measures].[Range1]:[Measures].[Range2])

SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Total Amount],[Measures].[MyRange], [Measures].[rank], [Measures].[Range1], [Measures].[Range2]}  on 0,
    NON EMPTY (supli)   on 1

FROM [Detail Booking]
WHERE {[Checkin Date.Date].[2015]}
```

The results looks like this:

```
Proveedor    Importe              MyRange             rank          Range1      Range2
P1             0               0.0 - 999.0              1             0          999
P2            100              0.0 - 999.0              2             0          999
P3           618,27            1000.0 - 1999.0          3            1000        1999
P4           855               1000.0 - 1999.0          4            1000        1999
P5           3819,5            4000.0 - 4999.0          5            4000        4999
P6           11669,23         12000.0 - 12999.0         6            12000      12999
P7           12000            12000.0 - 12999.0         7            12000      12999
P8          14805,49          15000.0 - 15999.0         8            15000      15999
P9          16784,4           17000.0 - 17999.0         9            17000      17999
P10          46967,7          47000.0 - 47999.0        10            47000      47999
```

There are about 500 suppliers and I don't know how many ranges there are or what ranges exists

I need the query returns results like this:

```
 Proveedor                count(supplier)
 0.0 - 999.0                    2
 1000.0 - 1999.0                2
 4000.0 - 4999.0                1
 12000.0 - 12999.0              2
 15000.0 - 15999.0              1
 17000.0 - 17999.0              1
 47000.0 - 47999.0              1
```

My problem is I don't know how to create a query with dynamically aggregates

I know I can aggregate  using something like this:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[0:1000] as 
    Count(
        Filter({[Supplier].[Supplier].CurrentMember}, 
            [Measures].[Total Amount] < 1000), 
        EXCLUDEEMPTY)
MEMBER [Supplier].[Supplier].[0€-1000€] as Aggregate({[Supplier].[Supplier].Members},[Measures].[0:1000])

MEMBER [Measures].[1000:2000] as 
    Count(
        Filter({[Supplier].[Supplier].CurrentMember}, 
            [Measures].[Total Amount] >= 1000 and [Measures].[Total Amount] < 2000), 
        EXCLUDEEMPTY)
MEMBER [Supplier].[Supplier].[1000€-2000€] as Aggregate({[Supplier].[Supplier].Members}, [Measures].[1000:2000])

member [Measures].[Total proveedores] as [Measures].[Total Amount], FORMAT_STRING ="####0"

SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Total proveedores]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY {[Supplier].[0€-1000€], [Supplier].[1000€-2000€]} ON 1 
FROM [Detail Booking]
WHERE {[Checkin Date.Date].[2015]}
```

My problem is that :there are about 500 suppliers and I don't know how many ranges there are or what ranges exists to use filters

Somebody knows how can I solve this?

Comment: Why can't you handle this requirement during the design phase(database and cube) instead of having to write a complicated query to get you the results?

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I've tried to do at first with query. I am not sure how I should do this , I do not know if I should add a hierarchy depending on the rank you belong to each supplier or if on the other hand add range parameters for each supplier (sorry for my english), i'm a beginner with this

Comment: @Constanzaforteza I wonder if a recursive solution might be possible?

Comment: @whytheq thanks for your tip, but i have no idea how can i do this with mondrian mdx. Do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed explanation here
https://sqlmdx.net/2021/02/02/group-by-an-expression-and-limitations-mdx-vs-sql/

To cut long story short - it's not possible to add unknown number of members to some dimension to do it nice and easy in MDX however there are some alternative approaches without changing the cube design.